# boost - thread.join() halts the ui

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I read that join blocks the thread that called it until the thread function returns. So if my main thread creates a boost thread and then calls join then my main thread would be blocked.
In my case the ui is the main thread and it needs to wait for the thread to finish before it could execute the next statement and when I use thread.join() then the UI freezes. I currently have something like this

```
boost::thread t(&Myclass::mymethod,ptr,parameter);
t.join();  //This blocks the ui
SomeOtherMethd();
```

Now my question is how can I wait for thread t to end and then call SomeOtherMethod without blocking the UI. Since t.join() seems to freeze the ui

Comment: The usual way is to let the main loop going, and check (non blocking) for e.g. a semaphore or condition variable that indicates the thread function has finished it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Qt, the non-blocking way of doing that is:

- from your working thread send a signal
- make **SomeOtherMethd()** a slot

For reference, have a look at the [Mandelbrot Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-mandelbrot.html) from Qt Project, that uses a queued connection to communicate between working and main threads.

Answer (score 1):

Give the thread a function that does what you need in sequential mode, in the correct order. This is a simplified example:

```
void foo()
{
  ptr->mymethod(parameter);
  SomeOtherMethod();
}

boost::thread t(foo);

// do other stuff while thread runs

t.join()
```

Comment: @MistyD Yes, but this can happen when you are done with everything. The point is that `SomethOtherMethod` happens after the call to `ptr->mymethod()`, without blocking. You can do all kinds of stuff between launching the thread and the call to `join()`.